# Why is Protege not able to infer all implicit axioms in one operation?

Tags: ontology, protege, pellet, reasoner, hermit

I use Pellet/Hermit to reason on the following family ontology and export all the inferred axioms to a new family ontology. Then I reason on the new ontology and export all the inferred axioms to another new family ontology again. New axioms are found to be inferred. **Is it necessary to reason on the ontology repeatedly to get all implicit axioms which can be inferred from the ontology?**

Code body is limited to 30000 characters by StackOverflow, however, the family ontology contains 149200 characters.

The following 143KB family is the original ontology which contains 728 axioms;

The 202KB one is the exported ontology containing axioms inferred on the 143KB one by pellet (once) and having 1306 axioms;

The 516KB one is the exported ontology containing axioms inferred on the 202KB one by pellet (twice)  and having 3987 axioms;

The 543KB one is the exported ontology containing axioms inferred on the 516KB one by pellet (three times)  and having 4220 axioms.  For example, there is no hasSon(aunt_0_RQM, child_8_ACF) in family_inferred2 which is contained by family_inferred3.

[there is no hasSon(aunt_0_RQM, child_8_ACF) in family_inferred2 which is contained by family_inferred3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5TC8.png)

**Every time I reason on the exported ontology, new axioms are inferred. Therefore, there are always some axioms not inferred by the reasoner.**

download link for family: [143KB](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1To7R9zJvenlB4OIOR2R_sA?pwd=4vy9)

download link for family_inferred1: [202KB](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1NuVJWz0mYMEQFddEe1iNaQ?pwd=vxt9)

download link for family_inferred2: [516KB](https://pan.baidu.com/s/15v_Y1wUSOuWLDxdkO4Tbcg?pwd=6v4h)

download link for family_inferred3: [543KB](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1Hn3_LC4uT_E6KCqubH8Pww?pwd=y5zx)

Comment: Please add an example of an axiom that is in inferred2 but not in inferred1, it will make it easier to explain what is going on. Inferring an axiom is different from finding it asserted in the ontology.

Comment: Please read the guidance regarding asking questions using [minimal, reproducable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is at least partially the reason why StackOverflow has a limit on the number of characters in a code block.

Comment: family_inferred3 contains 23 new axioms which are inferred from the family_inferred2. For example, there is no hasSon(aunt_0_RQM, child_8_ACF) in family_inferred2 which is contained by family_inferred3.